# Are probability distributions also distributions in the sense of a Schwartz distribution?

Tags: terminology, definition

I was trying to understand what the difference is between a distribution and a function. This question was answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987998/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-and-a-distribution#:%7E:text=A%20distribution%20is%20also%20a,is%20rather%20difficult%20to%20define).

However when I read about probability distributions on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution), the article says, that such a distribution is "the mathematical function that...". So a probability distribution IS a function, yet distributions and functions are distinct mathematical objects. So a probability distribution should not be a (Schwartz) distribution, right? And probability distribution is just a fancy name for a specific kind of function, whereas a distribution is a mathematical object, right?

Comment: Holy crap, that Wikipedia definition is terrible. A probability distribution is not a function. I think what Wikipedia was getting at is that probability distributions on a finite set can alternatively be represented as functions, in a very natural way. However, the uniform distribution over $[0,1]$, for example, is a probability distribution, but it's certainly not a function on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ can be viewed as a Schwartz distribution on $\mathbb{R}^d$, namely a continous linear map on $\mathcal{S}({R}^d)$, namely
$$T_\mu : \varphi \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\varphi\mathrm{d}\mu.$$
The continuity of this linear form follows from the equality
$$|T_\mu(\varphi)| \le ||\varphi||_\infty.$$